# LaTeX not generating the pdf

Tags: errors, compilation-error

So I am using the latex model that my university gave to me, and I am receiving the following error message:

```
Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "trabalho".tex

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/Ettore T/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "trabalho".tex

Process exited with error(s)



Process started: bibtex.exe "trabalho"

I couldn't open file name `trabalho.aux'

Process exited normally





Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "trabalho".tex

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/Ettore T/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "trabalho".tex

Process exited with error(s)



Process started: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "trabalho".tex

Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed. The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again: C:/Users/Ettore T/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log You may want to visit the MiKTeX project page, if you need help.

Error: Command crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "trabalho".tex

Process exited with error(s)

You have requested, on input line 5261, version `2018/04/30' of package array, but only version `2016/10/06 v2.4d Tabular extension package (FMi)' is available.
```

I do not know how to fix it. Also, the files are here
https://github.com/eturatti/Tese
The main file is Trabalho.tex

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to open the MikTeX console and update the `array` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. One problem is that your file `pacotes.tex` contains `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but also `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` a few lines later. (You also load several other packages multiple times.) Remove the second `inputenc`.